# Merging features in shapefile with same name and concatenate all attributes as single field

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, merge, attribute-joins, overlapping-features

I've got a dataset of tiles with individual attributes (NAME,date,sensor). All tiles have the same size.
After dissolving layer, in some locations tiles with the same NAME attribute overlap each other but have different sensor and date
I need to merge geometry of tiles and concatenate sensor and date attribute separated with sign "/". Is there any way to do it with the QGIS field calculator and "Join attributes by location"?
I have tried use "Join attributes by location" but as an output still I get overlapping shapes.

[image: multiple overlapped tiles]

Final attributes should look like:
[image]

Comment: Could you share your layer?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Use the (criminally underused) 'Aggregate' tool in the Processing Toolbox.

Group by `name`; set `first_value` as the aggregate function for the `name` field, and `concatenate_unique` for the other two fields, using `/` as the delimiter (if that's how you want it).

---

Sample data - note two distinct name values, `111` and `123`

[image]

Processing options:

[image]

Result:

[image]

---

The tool will concatenate attributes based on the order of your features in your source file.

If you want the concatenated values to be in a specific order regardless of source file feature order, then you may need to either (a) use Virtual Layer to set the order of your features before concatenating, or (b) post-process the aggregated data using an expression like below in Field Calculator (may be cumbersome if you have lots of fields or need to run the aggregation multiple times).

For example to make sure the aggregated sensor field shows `sensor1/sensor2` instead of `sensor2/sensor1`, use the expression below in Field Calculator on the aggregated layer:

```
array_to_string(array_sort(string_to_array("sensor",'/')),'/')
```

Comment: Happy to see you back with your marvelous answers :)

Comment: Haha, thanks. I've had to take a break after spending a bit too much time here instead of doing my actual job...

Comment: Can fully understand you :)

Comment: You have made great job. Thank you for help :)

Comment: If the answer has helped you don't forget to mark it as accepted so that others will find it easier to get to this solution.